# Access: Events in Parent Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm still fiddling around with MS Access and it's driving me crazy. My current problem is the following: I recreated the record navigation bar as a subform and added it to my mainform. This code is used in the subform

```
...
Private WithEvents frmParent As Access.Form
...

Private Sub Form_Load()
   ...
   Set frmParent = Me.Parent
   frmParent.OnCurrent = "[Event Procedure]"
   frmParent.Recordset.MoveLast
   frmParent.Recordset.MoveFirst
   ...
End Sub

Private Sub frmParent_Current()
   If frmParent.CurrentRecord = frmParent.Recordset.Count Then
       Me.butNext.Enabled = False
   Else
       Me.butNext.Enabled = True
   End If
   If frmParent.CurrentRecord = 1 Then
       Me.butPrevious.Enabled = False
   Else
       Me.butPrevious.Enabled = True
   End If
End Sub
...
Other MainForm Events...
```

From this some problems arise. First: None of the events from MainForm fire. Second: from time to time (especially after errors) vba looses the reference to the mainform. I could use the Win32 API workaround with CopyMemory but this seems to be overkill.

I'm, as always, thankful for any help.

Many thanks

Jon

Comment: When you say the events don't fire, do you mean only in the parent form? Or even in the subform? If it is only in the parent form I'm not surprised as you are catching all the events in the subform.

Comment: I have to ask why you decided to put these nav-buttons in a subform? Your life would be simpler if you placed them directly on the form, perhaps using a Rectangle to group them (visually).

Comment: As I have many many forms and I would like to have the same behaviour and look in all of them I decided to go that way. @EMett: Only the events in the mainform, the subform works as intended.

Comment: I think, like I wrote in an earlier comment, that events are not broadcast, rather they are fired to the code that is wired up to them, in this case the subform. Therefore the main form is not receiving them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this seems to be a bug in Access... Just create a code-file for the parent form in question even if it stays empty and everything works fine.

Edit: I have to correct myself. This is intended behaviour. Taken from Litwin et.al.: Access 2002 Desktop Developer's handbook, p. 508

> ... if you're using a WithEvents variable to react to events of the form, the form must have an associated module. That is, if the HasModule property is False, Access doesn't bother raising events for the form, so any code outside the form expecting to react to the form's event will not get called by Access.

Comment: Interesting. By code-file, I guess you mean a module. Indeed I can imagine that if a form's HasModule property is set to No, events do not need to fire. Looks more like a feature than a bug ;-) Thanks for sharing !